# bootstrap datepicker start at a specific date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have bootstrap start at a specific date. Let say 01.05.1970. I have tried

`startDate` and `endDate` but they limit range. I would like that when the date picker is clicked it's started at that specific date.

This is the code that I currently have.

```
$('#NavCal').datepicker({
  //language: "<? echo strtolower(_("LANGUAGE_ALPHA_2"));?>", 
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    format: "yy-mm-dd",
    //startDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    //endDate: new Date('2030-01-01'),
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
     a = e.format(0,"yyyy-mm-dd");
     ........
});
```

I also tried this

```
//defaultViewDate: new Date(1977, 1, 1),
    //defaultViewDate: {year:1977, month:01, day:28},
    //defaultViewDate: new Date('1977-01-01'),
    defaultViewDate: '1977, 1, 1',
```

But none seem to work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default date for bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092231/set-default-date-for-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882279/set-default-date-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795079/bootstrap-3-datepicker-v4-set-default-date

Answer (score 0):

Use the defaultViewDate option.

```
$('#NavCal').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    defaultViewDate: '2000-01-01'
});
```

You can see all the available options [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html).